# how to upload data to my website database from an android app

Tags: java, php, android

I want to create an android app to upload products details to my website database, but the app don't send any data, please help me to fix the errors, those are all the codes i use :

I use this void code in my android app , i use the Volley HTTP library :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
}
```

```
public void _uploadProduct(final String _product_name, final String _product_description) {
    url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/add_product.php";

    final String productName = _product_name;
    final String productDescription = _product_description;

    // Log the product name and description
    Log.d("MyApp", "Product Name: " + productName);
    Log.d("MyApp", "Product Description: " + productDescription);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Handle the response from the server
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    String message = jsonResponse.getString("message");

                    // Display a success message to the user
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // Clear input fields
                    edittext1.setText("");
                    edittext2.setText("");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Handle error responses from the server
                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Error uploading product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Upload Error", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
        // Define the parameters to be sent to the server
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("_product_name", productName);
            params.put("_product_description", productDescription);
            // Add more parameters if needed
            return params;
        }
    };

    // Add the request to the request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

and in the upload button i use this code :

```
productName = edittext1.getText().toString();
productDescription = edittext2.getText().toString();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(productName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(productDescription)) {
        // Make the network request
        
    _uploadProduct(productName, productDescription);
    
} else {
        // Handle the case where the values are empty
        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Product name and description cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and i use this php code on my website code source :

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Check if the required POST fields exist
    if (isset($_POST['product_name']) && isset($_POST['product_description'])) {
        // Get the product data from the POST request
        $productName = $_POST['product_name'];
        $productDescription = $_POST['product_description'];

        // Prepare and execute the database query to insert the product data
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO products (product_name, description) VALUES (?, ?)");
        if ($stmt->execute([$productName, $productDescription])) {
            $response = ["message" => "Product uploaded successfully"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            $response = ["message" => "Error uploading product"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        $response = ["message" => "Missing product_name or product_description"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response = ["message" => "Invalid request method"];
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

the data is not uploaded, and the app show this error : " missing product_name or product_description "

Answer (score 0):

In getParams() method, can you remove the underscore (_) before the product_name and product_description and try?

Replace the below one

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("_product_name", productName);
    params.put("_product_description", productDescription);
    // Add more parameters if needed
    return params;
}
```

to:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("product_name", productName);
    params.put("product_description", productDescription);
    // Add more parameters if needed
    return params;
}
```

Comment: No, when i remove the _ the app don't do anything, the data is not uploaded and don't show any error